# How to read this JSON response from AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

This is my response from AJAX call

```
{"screen":[{"screen_name":"SCR1","screen_id":"1"},{"screen_name":"SCR2","screen_id":"2"},{"screen_name":"SCR3","screen_id":"3"},{"screen_name":"SCR4","screen_id":"4"},{"screen_name":"SCR5","screen_id":"5"},{"screen_name":"BIGSCR","screen_id":"6"}]}
```

```
success: function(response) {
    var jsondata = JSON.stringify(response);
    console.log(jsondata);
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < jsondata.screen.length; i++) {
        var screenName = jsondata.screen[i].screen_name;
        var screenId = jsondata.screen[i].screen_id;
        html += '<option value="' + screenName + '">' + screenId + '</option>';
    }
    $('#SCname').append(html);
}
```

But I keep on getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at for loop

Comment: `jsondata` is the string you presumably created to log. If you want the object, use `response.screen`.

Comment: The error message is because `jsondata` is a string and has no property called `screen`. You do not need to call `JSON.stringify`; jQuery will decode your AJAX response for you if you set `dataType: 'json'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`JSON.stringify(object)` returns a string.** You want a `JSON.parse(string)` – which returns an object. Alternatively, if your `response` is *already an object*, then you don't have to parse it at all:

```
success: function(jsonData) {
      var html = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.screen.length; i++) {
          var screenName = jsonData.screen[i].screen_name;
          var screenId = jsonData.screen[i].screen_id;
          html += '<option value="' + screenName + '">' + screenId + '</option>';
      }
      $('#SCname').append(html);
```

Comment: Thanks @minitech, beat me to it. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this: It Works. As smooth as silk: (See comment for explanation)

```
<select id="SCname"></select>
<script>
    $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            //This JSON datatype returns a json encoded response
            url:"api/test.php",
            //This is the URL From where you fetch the JSON Data
            success: function(response){
                //Since the response array object has a single array element "screen", we make it myArray
                myArray = response["screen"];
                console.log(myArray);
                //We get six Objects in myArray.
                //Thsese are Arrays of your six screens . Now Using Loops
                var html = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
                    // Each element is inside DOuble Array like: myArray[0]["screen_name"]
                    var screenName = myArray[i]["screen_name"];
                    var screenId = myArray[i]["screen_id"];
                    html += '<option value="' + screenName + '">' + screenId + '</option>';
                }
                $('#SCname').append(html);

                //Check your console ouput
                console.log(html);
            }  
      });
</script>
```

Comment: @CaseyFalk I will add it asap

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to `stringify`but to `parse`. Correct it must be:

```
var jsondata = JSON.parse(response);
```

But keep in mind that jQuery possibly is already parsing the JSON for you.

Comment: "jQuery probably is already parsing the JSON for you." -- not necessarily. This is what `$.getJSON` is for.

Comment: @CaseyFalk: jQuery actually detects JSON from `Content-Type`, and there’s a `datatype` option, too.

Comment: @minitech, Ahh, fair enough. I wasn't assuming that the OP had set the `datatype`  since it was not included in the question. Good point on `Content-Type` though.